# What does the "VimTouch Full Runtime" do?

Tags: vimtouch

I just installed [VimTouch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch&feature=more_from_developer); it works as well as you expect a text editor to work on a phone. What is the point of the separate "[VimTouch Full Runtime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch.fullruntime)" app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From browsing [the source code](https://github.com/momodalo/vimtouch_fullruntime), this appears to be the same as the vim-runtime package as provided in most Linux distributions. It ships [a variety of Vim scripts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Understanding_VIMRUNTIME) which provide additional functionality, such as additional color schemes, file type handling, automatic indentation, etc.

Without this package, Vim operates in a minimal mode and many features that are provided by these scripts are not available.